# Connecting to SQL Server from within an SSIS script task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb

In SSIS, I have defined a `Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 11.0` connection that I've called`MyConnection`.

Then I've created a data flow task, and within the Data Flow of that task there is:

1. A flat file source (from a CSV)
2. A script component in which I'm taking the CSV output and inserting to tables via first staging in a TVP.

Within the script component I want to connect to the database using `MyConnection`, but I see in
    the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/connecting-to-data-sources-in-the-script-task):

> You cannot call the AcquireConnection method of connection managers
>   that return unmanaged objects, such as the OLE DB connection manager
>   and the Excel connection manager, in the managed code of a Script
>   task. However, you can read the ConnectionString property of these
>   connection managers, and connect to the data source directly in your
>   code by using the connection string with an OledbConnection from the
>   System.Data.OleDb namespace.

That seems straightforward enough, so in my script task code I retrieve the connection string and try to use that to create a connection:

```
string conString = Connections.MyConnection.ConnectionString;
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{
    try
    {
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) con.Open();
        ...
```

And I get the error that authentication failed for the user. In the connection string there is no password (I'm using SQL Server authentication). I did check the box 'Save password' in the connection manager.

**How do I use a connection defined in the project scope from within a script component?**

When I provide the string explicitly, everything works. Also. Why can I not define the connection as anything but an `Ole` connection in the main package?

Comment: Take it back a step - are you _certain_ you need to use a script task? Because I see a lot of questions on here from people using scripts when they don't need to. It's a long story but generally speaking passwords are never saved in connection strings. The entire story is very confusing but it's all about protection levels and not saving passwords in clear text. The easiest way around this is to just use windows authentication, or don't use a script task if you don't have to

Comment: From what I've read that is the way to parse into a TVP from SSIS... Do I need to use a TVP? Now that is a good question...

Comment: Yes it is a good question. What are you trying to do and is all the data  (the data populating the TVP and the stored procedure itself) in the same SQL Server?

Comment: For now the SQL Server instance and the data will be on the same box. The CSVs are about 100mb each, but are likely to get much bigger (from a 3rd party provider)

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain where CSV's come into this. Are you reading data from CSV's and loading into a TVP and running a stored procedure?

Comment: Edited @Nick.McDermaid. Yes, the script creates a DataTable, and calls an SP with that DataTable as a parameter

Comment: Not sure which version of Visual Studio you're using to develop the SSIS packages, but I always had issues when I updated or even viewed my connections.  If I did not re-enter my password for that connection EVERY time I opened it to view it in the UI (even if I wasn't changing anything), it would make the connection fail.

Comment: Well... consider using windows authentication then you don't have to worry about passwords. You _can_ get around it by loading your connection string from an expression but you are basically bypassing security that has been put there for a reason

Comment: @MguerraTorres - I don't have that issue, but there are numerous bugs I've found in SSDT 17.1, mostly involving the UI. It often freezes.

Comment: That's a good idea @Nick.McDermaid. Since it's deployed on the same machine as a server, that does seem like the best solution